# shape keys made from other shape keys

Tags: shape-keys

Is it possible to make new shape keys using varying amounts of other shape keys.

For example let's say I have two shape keys one for the upper lip and one for the lower lip. Can I create a third shape key using a bit of both previously created shape keys to move both lips at once to spare time?

Comment: you can probably just use relative shape keys and animate them as you wish https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/shape_keys_panel.html#relative-shape-keys

Comment: You can layer shapekeys so both upper and lower lip will move when you have both shape keys added. Or you can make a third shape key that  affects vertices in the upper and lower lip and add that in the mix. Depends on your case which works best.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and easy (check image below). By adjusting value of previous keyframes, you get different mixtures of them.
[image]

Comment: @Jesper Petersen Don't forget to check the **From Mix** checkbox in a Tool Shelf after adding a new shape key- it isn't checked by default.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the info an image! You've been very helpful :-)